# Select the maximum day of every month in Power Query in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have the following dataset in power BI :

[image]

I'd like to select for every month/year, ONLY the rows with highest day (and delete the rest).

In this example, the rows 4-7 would be deleted

Do you have any idea how to approach this problem ?

Thank you,

Best

Edit : month AND year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont mention it, but don't you have to check year as well? Anyway, one way is to break it down to year, month, day, find the max day for the year/month combination, see if it matches the day on that row, then filter

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "YearMonth", each Date.Year([Date])*1000+Date.Month([Date])),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"YearMonth"}, {{"data", each 
    let a = List.Max(_[Date]),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(_, "Custom", (x)=>if x[Date]<> a then "XX" else null),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom2", each [Custom] = null)
    in #"Filtered Rows"
, type table [Date=nullable date]}}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"data"}), "data", Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"))
in #"Expanded Data"
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my post, yeah it is month and year. 
I will try your solution and let you know, thank you !

Comment: I had trouble implementing it in my actual dataframe, but it's finally working !
Thank you very much,